# Get Express Route URL in NodeJS with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path, routeparams

I have a problem with my application made in Express 4.x, I have an authentication Middleware checking for the route called and I would like to get the route without parameters ...

Example :

I declared this route : `/authentication/newPassword/:token` 
So I would like to know if the request.path matches this particular route...

This is my url : `/authenticate/newPassword/XRlIjoiMjAxOC0wOC0xM1QwOTNzo1Mi43ODBaIn0=`

So I was looking in differents variables :

```
req.path         // /authenticate/newPassword/XRlIjoiMjAxOC0wOC0xM1QwOTNzo1Mi43ODBaIn0=
req.originalUrl  // /authenticate/newPassword/XRlIjoiMjAxOC0wOC0xM1QwOTNzo1Mi43ODBaIn0=
req.url          // /authenticate/newPassword/XRlIjoiMjAxOC0wOC0xM1QwOTNzo1Mi43ODBaIn0=
req.pathname     // undefined
```

*I was looking on google and I saw someone answering the use of req.headers, with the .refers to know the path, but my express aplication is an **API** and it's called by other Applications on other URL so referrers don't match the good url*

I found a solution to my problem using regexp like this :

```
const pathOk = /\/authenticate\/newPassword\/.+/;
if(pathOk.test(req.path)) { //Continue the middleware ...
```

So my question is easy, is there something in Express or Node to make something like that :

```
if (req.{something like path} == '/authentication/newPassword/:token') {
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express uses [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) for matching the route paths.

Using this module, you can automatically create a regular expression from your route string.

```
var pathToRegexp = require('path-to-regexp')
var re = pathToRegexp('/authentication/newPassword/:token')
if(re.test(req.path)) { //...
```

Or in a one liner:

```
if (require('path-to-regexp')('/authentication/newPassword/:token').test(req.path) { //...
```